# Why I had different output for this code by doing same operation

Tags: c, math

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float x, y ,z,p;
    x = 22;
    y = 7;
    
    p = 22/7;
    
    z = x/y;
    
    printf("%f\n",z); //output is 3.142857
    printf("%f",p);   //output is 3.000000

    return 0;
}
```

`Why I had different output like this
z = 3.142857
p = 3.000000

why all decimals are 0 in p and what is the different between this two methods and what is the correct method`

Comment: `22/7` is integer division. `x/y` is floating point division. Try `22.0f/7.0f` instead

Comment: 355.0 / 113.0 is a much better approximation to π

Comment: In `x = 22`, even though `22` is an integer, since `x` is a float, there's an automatic (implicit) conversion from `int` to `float`.  And then in `x/y`, you've obviously got floating-point division.  But when you write `22/7`, both `22` and `7` are `int`s, and there's noting to tell the compiler you want anything else, so it sticks with integer (truncating) division.